# Fastest way to store table of data and retrieve

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, serialization

I am storing some history information on my website for future retrieval of the users.  So when they visit certain pages it will record the page that they visited, the time, and then store it under their user id for future additions/retrievals.

So my original plan was to store all of the data in an array, and then serialize/unserialize it on each retrieval and then store it back in a TEXT field in the database.  The problem is: I don't know how efficient or inefficient this will get with large arrays of data if the user builds up a history of (e.g.) 10k pages.

EDIT: So I want to know what is the most efficient way to do this?  I was also considering just inserting a new row in the database for each and every history, but then this would make a large database for selecting things from.

The question is what is faster/efficient, massive amount of rows in database or massive serialized array?  Any other better solutions are obviously welcome.  I will eventually be switching to Python, but for now this has to be done in PHP.

Comment: You will need some upper bounds as to the number of pages and the time. Otherwise use summat like SVN and make the ids on the fly.

Comment: I guess you never intend to display 10k of data in the user's history page. Display a 20-liner history, and place a "more" link to add more data to the page. In the case of Facebook's timeline profile, it adds more data as you scroll down the page, not all data at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no benefit to storing the data as serialized arrays. Retrieving a big blob of data, de-serializing, modifying it and re-serializing to update is slow - and worse, will get slower the larger the piece of data (exactly what you're worried about).

Databases are specifically designed to handle large numbers of rows, so use them. You have no extra cost per insert as the data grows, unlike your proposed method, and you're still storing the same *amount* of data, so let the database do what it does best, and keep your code simple.

Storing the data as an array also makes any sort of querying and aggregation near impossible. If the purpose of the system is to (for example) see how many visits a particular page got, you would have to de-serialize every record, find all the matching pages, etc. If you have the data as a series of rows with user and page, it's a trivial SQL count query.

If, one day, you find that you have so many rows (10,000 is not a lot of rows) that you're starting to see performance issues, find ways to optimize it, perhaps through aggregation and de-normalization.

Comment: Well...this will grow to probably a hundred thousand per week, maybe even more in a few months.  I would only grab lets say 30 at a time, and load them on request, and would be selected via user id and sorted by the time.  So obviously this will slow down when there are millions of records?  Or not?

Comment: Why would you need to load the user's complete history on each hit?

Comment: I wouldn't.  I said I would grab 30 rows and load more as requested (like hitting a button saying "Load More")  But all of this information will be being stored for thousands and thousands of users...

Comment: Oh, I understand now. No, as long as your table is correctly designed (eg, with indexes) there is little difference. This is exactly that databases are designed to do, after all.

Comment: Really?  I studied hash tables (which is what databases are based on, i think) but I never understood how it gets the data, for instance: SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = 10;  are the values of uid hashed to something else on the backend if it is indexed?  Like I insert 10 into the hashing algorithm and then it finds the right key to locate the row?  Just curious to understand how all of this works.  I know rehashing has to be done when there is too much data in the table, but no idea how this scales with millions of rows.

Comment: *"How does a RDBMS work"* is a bit beyond the scope of an SO question. That's mostly irrelevant though: this is what a database is *designed to do*. If you have so much data that a database struggles to handle it, attempting to store it *all* in a giant blob for serialization and attempting to manipulate it in memory is going to be *at least* 100x worse for performance.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the info :)  I will research RDBMS on my own just because I am curious on how it works.  Didn't know what databases were classified under before :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can check for session variable and store all data of one session and can dump it together into database.

You can do Indexing at db level to save time.

Last and the most effective thing you can do is to do operation/manipulation on data and store it in separate table.And always select data from manuplated table.You can achieve this using cron job or some schedular.